# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a different value from the insert

Tags: mysql

I would like to do something like this (the *updated* value should be different than the *inserted* value):

```
"INSERT INTO notification_chat_counts (uid,group_id,count)
                            VALUES
                                    (",$uid,",",$groupId,",1)
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                                    (count = count +1)"
```

Comment: What's the problem/error?

Comment: I need to write after update which column value I want to put in case of duplicate,  the value from the insert that is,  on my case I just wanna update the count with a different value from what I put in the insert, is it possible? I dont think its possible the way I wrote it(syntax wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Even the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) has example of inserting different value that the values which would got updated:

`INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`

For your example, the correct query syntax would be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO notification_chat_counts (uid,group_id,count)
          VALUES (",$uid,",",$groupId,",1)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1"
```

However for this statement to work you must have an `UNIQUE` type index defined for this table, so that MySQL can decide if such row already exists in the table or not.

Also remember that inserting values into SQL query like this is dangerous and not recommended. You should use prepared statements for that.

Comment: But note: If you have a surrogate auto-incremental id defined, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will consume one of these ids, leading to gaps for the next *real* insert!

Comment: Yes, that's true (and mentioned in the linked manual page). Anyway, auto-increment isn't guaranteed to be gap-free (deletions, insert with manually specified id, ...).

Comment: yeah, just as an Addition for the OP. Example of what i meant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5868a2/1